# jQuery divide a number but keep decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm hoping for a bit of help with this issue I have.

I basically have a number... say 3000 and I want to display 30.00 on the front end without changing my variable (lots of reasons why I can't change it, I've just simplified this for the question)

```
HTML:
<span class="number"></span>

JS: 
var three = 3000;
$('.number').append(three/100);
```

This returns '30' to my span. How can I keep the decimal points?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Number.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) should do the trick:

```
var three = 3000,
    result = (three/100).toFixed(2);

$('.number').append(result);
```

If you're concerned about `toFixed()` rounding, there are a lot of SO threads covering that topic.

Comment: Perfect! I was playing around with toFixed earlier but couldn't get any results from it. I didn't pass it to a variable prior to appending so that might have had some impact. Anyway, thank you so much, I'll upvote when it lets me! :)

Comment: @LiamTarpey Np - glad to help!